# How to edit Azure Active Directory B2C administrator email list?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal

When a user goes through the process of trying to reset their password, they go through the below process:

[image]

Then once the above is submitted, administrators of the Azure Active Directory B2C instance get the following email:

[image]

How do I edit the red circled list of "to" email addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I edit the red circled list of "to" email addresses?

The contact email is sent to the following recipients in the following order:

> - If the password administrator role is assigned, administrators with this role are notified.
> - If no password administrators are assigned, then administrators with the user administrator role are notified.
> - If neither of the previous roles are assigned, then the global administrators are notified.

We also could [customize the list of the emails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-customization#disable-contact-your-administrator-emails). This option is under Password Reset > Customization > Custom helpdesk email or URL.

> Customize the helpdesk link to provide a web URL or mailto: address that users can use to get assistance. This option is under Password Reset > Customization > Custom helpdesk email or URL.

[image]